# How would I display the image uploaded with this PHP script?

Tags: php, image

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

I just want to get this image I'm uploading to display on the browser page! Help! I have the file uploading correctly so I'm not worried about the HTML as much as the php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to create a database and table. In the table you should mention the path (field name) which the file is going to be uploaded in varchar format. After that when you move the file (**move_uploaded_file(....)**), you have to insert the path into database. then you can easily retrieve if from database by using php.

Eg :-

```
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

      $sql_run=mysqli(**$YOUR_CONNECTION,"INSERT INTO yourTable(path) VALUE ('YOUR_PATH_NAME/FILE_NAME')**");
      if($sql_run)
      echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";

        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
```

then another phpfile

```
<?php
//SELECT query
?>
<img src="YOUR PATH/<?php echo $mysqli_fetch_assoc(....)?>">
?>
```

Comment: I actually figured it out a much easier way!

<img src="<?php echo $target_file; ?>" />

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<?php echo $target_file; ?>" />
```

That's what I used, and it worked fine!